# Html5 video not starting at 0:00 when recording in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome, html5-video

This issue it's only happening in latest current version of Chrome while using macOS.

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: true
      });
```

Example code in this codepen

https://codepen.io/pvillegasm/pen/yLMYeoK

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: Sure, if you open the snippet and click in the open camera button, the timer should start like any normal video, at 0:00, while this is fine in any browsers for windows and most for mac, in chrome, after I click the open camera button, the timer starts at much bigger time, instead of 0:00, 30:00:00+

Comment: Sounds like it's just using the timestamp from the media device, which is usually desirable.  If you need to display something different, you should use your own HTML/CSS for that, and turn off controls on the video element.

Comment: I understand, but i need the timer to start at 0 since eventually i need to playback the video as a recording and a correct timestamp is a must, which is working fine in all other browsers except chrome

Comment: The thing is though, the timestamp *is* correct... it just doesn't start at zero.  I'm not sure you'll be able to use MediaRecorder to change the timestamp here.  You may need to do that with something like FFmpeg on the server-side.

Comment: Not sure about being correct while this behavior its only present in Chrome while using a Mac, all other browsers the timestamp starts at 0:00, and Chrome too in Windows, thanks for the feedback tho.